# What's the build order of product-am and carbon-apimgt?

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I got product-am and carbon-apimgt source code from github.
How to build and make it work? What's the order of building?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to build the `carbon-apimgt` repo and next, build the `product-apim` repo. Then the product pack can be found within the `product-apim/modules/distribution/product/target` directory. You can get the relevant zip file of the pack and run it by following the steps mentioned [here](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim#installation--running).

If you are building the `master` branch, make sure you have fetched the latest changes from both the `carbon-apimgt` repo and the `product-apim` repo. First build the `carbon-apimgt` master branch. Then copy the value within the `<version>` tag of the `pom.xml` of the `carbon-apimgt` master branch and add it as the `<carbon.apimgt.version>` of the `pom.xml` of the `product-apim` master branch. (The value within the `<version>` tag of `carbon-apimgt` `pom.xml` and the value within the `<carbon.apimgt.version>` tag of the `product-apim` `pom.xml` should be the same). Then build the `product-apim` master branch. Then the product pack can be found within the `product-apim/modules/distribution/product/target` directory.

If you want to build a specific version of API Manager (Let's say API-M 4.0.0), first checkout to the relevant tag of the released version in the `product-apim` repo (v4.0.0). Then check the `<carbon.apimgt.version>` tag of the `product-apim` `pom.xml` (9.0.174). Next, go the `carbon-apimgt` repo and checkout to this relevant tag (v9.0.174). Then you can first build the `carbon-apimgt` repo and afterwards build the `product-apim` repo to get the relevant API-M pack.