# How to run and debug api manager source code in intellig idea?

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I have apim source code from github, How can i add some code to the project and build as new ? How to run and debug in intellij idea?

Comment: Which component do you need to customise? You need to extend the WSO2 code and do the required changes to your project. That's the best practice. Eg. If you want to create a customised mediator, then you need to extend the "org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractMediator" code on your project and do the required changes(https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/integrate/develop/customizations/creating-custom-mediators/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to add backend changes, you can do the necessary changes in the [carbon-apimgt](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt) repository. Once the changes have been done, if you are looking to build a new pack with your changes, you can follow the steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70727605/15497831). You can follow [this guide](https://medium.com/api-integration-essentials/wso2-api-manager-remote-debugging-using-intellij-idea-18f788436e4d) to debug using IntelliJ IDEA.

If you are looking to add frontend changes, you can follow the steps mentioned [here](https://github.com/wso2/apim-apps#building--running).